# MySQL create trigger with query and aggregation function

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mySQL and struggling here to create a trigger.

What I want is a trigger that checks before insert a new row to table A. If table A has more then 50 data in the past 1 hour, drop the new row.

Following code is what I came up with, but this is not correct. Please help me fix it.

```
create trigger before_A_insert
before insert on A
for each row
begin
    declare temp int default 0
    set temp = (
        select  count(*)
        from    A
        where   id = new.id and timestampdiff(minute, new.starttime, starttime) < 60
    )
    if temp = 50 then
        set new.id = null
    end if
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't drop the new row, it just inserts a new row with `id` set to `NULL`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is there a way to drop the new row? My logic here is just letting it throw an exception, assuming that id cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_A_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON A FOR EACH ROW
begin

declare temp int default 0

     select  count(*) into @temp from A where id = new.id and timestampdiff(minute, new.starttime, starttime) < 60);
    if @temp = 50 then
        set new.id = null;
    end if;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't know your query logic is, This is just constructing passing variable from query.

Comment: I tested the code and it returns a syntax error. Did I do anything wrong? My logic here was trying to count the data for new.id that is added within 60 min. And if the count reaches 50, drop the new row. I set the id to null so it terminates and throws an exception. Is there a better way to drop the new row?

Comment: Are you sure your table name is A?

Comment: show the error returns here. Make sure your function timestampdiff is working.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select  count(*) into @temp from Trips where id = new.id and timestampdiff(minut' at line 7

Comment: Yes, I double checked. timestampdiff() should be fine